# {Soutput} environment for asis with render_sweave hooks in knitr

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I'm processing Rnw files with `knitr` and want to include the results `"asis"`. In plain `knitr` this works fine but after enabling the `render_sweave` hooks an `{Soutput}` environment is wrapped around the `"asis"` results. As `Sweave()` does not have this behavior, this seems to be inconsistent to me. Is this intended/documented behavior? I couldn't find this described anywhere (e.g., https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/). The reasons this bit me is that I'm not running LaTeX directly on the output but parse it partially first (within the R/exams package).

The issue is illustrated with a minimal `foo.Rnw` file in `knitr` style, processed with plain `knitr::knit()` first:

```
writeLines('
<<echo=FALSE, results="asis">>=
writeLines("Hello World!")
@
', "foo.Rnw")

knitr::knit("foo.Rnw", quiet = TRUE)
writeLines(readLines("foo.tex"))
##
## Hello World!
##
```

However, after setting the `render_sweave()` hook:

```
knitr::render_sweave()
knitr::knit("foo.Rnw", quiet = TRUE)
writeLines(readLines("foo.tex"))
## 
## \begin{Soutput}
## Hello World!
## \end{Soutput}
##
```

In contrast, doing this in `Sweave` style yields:

```
writeLines('
<<echo=FALSE, results=tex>>=
writeLines("Hello World!")
@  
', "foo.Rnw")

utils::Sweave("foo.Rnw", quiet = TRUE)
writeLines(readLines("foo.tex"))
## 
## Hello World!
```

Can I do anything to avoid this behavior, e.g., modify the `render_sweave` hooks manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug of **knitr** (many thanks for the report) and [I just fixed it](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/aefafdda941923f322a2957956f165c5c8038866) on Github. Basically I forgot to consider `results='asis'` in the `output` hook. For now, you can try the development version of **knitr**:

```r
remotes::install_github('yihui/knitr')
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tested it in my R/exams setup and it works like a charm.